# iOS app crashes on Segue

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to build an app for school but I keep getting error messages. It's probably a really obvious mistake I made.
Basically I am trying to build a view that displays a UIWebView and changes to a 2nd view if a segment controller switch is pressed.

My Code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://google.de")
        myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }

    @IBAction func Heute(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Switch", sender: self)
    }
}

//Vertretung2
class Vertretung2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UIWebView1: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://google.de")
         UIWebView1.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }

    @IBAction func Morgen(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Switch", sender: self)
    }
}
```

My app keeps crashing when I switch from 1st view to 2nd view.

Comment: what is crashing error?

Comment: 2017-09-08 21:36:21.660 web load[847:15600] Unknown class Vertretung2 in Interface Builder file.
2017-09-08 21:36:21.667 web load[847:15600] Unknown class UIWebView1 in Interface Builder file.
2017-09-08 21:36:21.675 web load[847:15600] Unknown class Vertretung2 in Interface Builder file.
2017-09-08 21:36:21.686 web load[847:15600] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ff653c1fe30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Morgen.'
)

Comment: check the outlet connection for your button.

Answer (score 0):

Is that UIWebView1 in Vertretung2 nil when viewDidLoad() is called on Vertretung2?

Ok, Sorry. I just read your crash log above, and it looks like you maybe forgot to set the Custom Class name in the storyboard for the viewController? Check that here.

[image]

The Class text entry field should have your custom class in it.

Comment: Yes, please share it somewhere and I can easily take a look. Thanks!